# How to print rows (lines) as columns in a text file?

Tags: java, text-files

I need to read a text file and printing its rows as columns.

So far all I have is

```
try
{ 
     Scanner sc  = null;    
     sc = new Scanner( new File("FinalTopFeatures.txt"));        
     String line= "";
     double[][] lines = null;
     int rows = sc.nextInt();
     int columns = sc.nextInt();
     while( sc.hasNextLine()){//While there are more lines
         String[] values = line.split(","); //Get the values
         lines = new double[rows][columns];
         for(int n = 0; n < lines.length; n++){
             for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){//For each value
                 System.out.println(values[i]+", ");//Print with a heading
             }
             n++;
         }
     }
} catch (Exception io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

but it printed all values in one column rather than multiple columns 
the inputs are like this

```
1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0 
-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 
1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0
-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
```

the outputs should be like this

```
1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0
1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
-1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0
```

Request help in resolving

Comment: If you need to print the first row as the first (left-most) column, and the second row as the second column, then you **cannot print while reading**, because the first row of the output needs values from all input rows. You need to read the data into a 2D array / list. Try again, because we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: thanks@Andreas. i updated the code with the 2D array but still getting the error java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at PSOFS.Sorting.main(Sorting.java:102)

Comment: Then your text file doesn't start with 2 integer values.

Comment: Yes all the values in text file are double

Comment: Also, don't initialize `lines` inside the `while` loop, and perhaps you should call `nextLine()` somewhere, don't you think?

Comment: *"all the values in text file are double"* So why are you trying to read 2 `int` values into `rows` and `columns`?

Comment: sorry for that mistake

Comment: I read 2D in int because the 2D array in the following line require int  lines = new double[rows][columns];

Comment: I will help you, do not worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class help
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        File file1 = new File("E://Javaprograms//xyz.txt");    //Try-With-Resources so we autoclose the reader after try block
        try
        { 
            Scanner sc  = null;    
            sc = new Scanner( file1);        
            String  line = "";
            int maxLen = 0;
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){//While there are more lines
                line = sc.nextLine();
                list.add(line);//add this line to list of string. Read about ArrayList.
                if(line.length() > maxLen)
                    maxLen = line.length(); //finding maximum length of line
            }
            int rows = maxLen;
            int col = list.size();
            double arr[][] = new double[rows][col];
            rows = 0; // rows initialized to zero. Go through code to know why?
            for(int i=0;i<col;i++)
            {
                String s = list.get(i); // getting line from list
                String values[] = s.split(","); // splitting them to hold double. Remember they are still String
                if(rows < values.length)
                    rows = values.length; // using this to determine the maximum length of a column or number of rows that will actually hold values. Other rows will simply contain not required values
                for(int j=0;j<values.length;j++)
                {
                    arr[j][i] = Double.parseDouble(values[j]);// converting string to double and storing them at their position
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(arr[i][j]+", ");// displaying numbers
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        } catch (Exception io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}
```

Please go through the above code. Comments are enough to describe the code.

Please learn about ArrayList, if you do not know about them.

I am adding image of the result below 
[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks @adarsh anurag. but it gives an error at the line  arr[j][i] = Double.parseDouble(values[j]);

Comment: this the error   java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1020)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
 at PSOFS.help.main(NewClass.java:39)

Comment: @user11801243 I am not getting any error. In your text file, please remove trailing new lines or empty lines. Try remove any extra spaces that follow your lines.

Comment: @user11801243 There should no line of spaces following the number lines in your text file.

Comment: yes with above example it is working, but this is just sample from my data, the lines  in text file are longer, the contain 691 column

Comment: @user11801243 It will work for any number of lines. But they should not be followed by empty lines. If not, try handling that error with try catch block or check the value of s which you get from the list.

Comment: I solved the problem.. it was related to the creation of the text file. Thanks and I will accept the answer

Comment: What does `line.length` have to do with number of result rows? Perhaps you meant to do `.length` *after* doing `.split(",")`, so you get the number of *values* in the input row, not the number of *characters*.

Comment: @Andreas, It is not necessary each row will have equal number of decimal numbers. As total numbers cannot be more than number of characters in a line, I used ```line.length``` to set a limit for array dimensions. Moreover, I would have to use ```.split(",")``` two times (once inside while and second time inside for).

Comment: @AdarshAnurag If the input is supposed to be a 2D array, then all input rows *will* (must) have the same number of values. --- Regardless of that, you should call `split` in the `while` loop and store that in the list (`List<String[]>`), so `maxLen` would be the max number of *values*, not *characters*.

Comment: @Andreas You are correct man. I forgot that we can do ```List<String[]>```. If I get time, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the matrix, transpose it then print it out.

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    try
    {
        Scanner sc  = null;
        sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\javaTest\\src\\file.txt"));
        String line= "";
        int rows = sc.nextInt();
        int columns = sc.nextInt();
        double[][] lines = new double[rows][columns];
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0;sc.hasNextLine();i++){//While there are more lines
            line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] values = line.split(","); //Get the values
            for(int j = 0; j < values.length; j++){
                lines[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(values[j]);
                System.out.println("[" + i + ", " + j + "]: " + lines[i][j]);
            }
        }
        sc.close();

        System.out.println("Transposed Matrix: ");
        double[][] tMatrix = transpose(lines);
        for(int i = 0;i< tMatrix.length;i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < tMatrix[i].length; j++)
                System.out.println("[" + i + ", " + j + "]: " + tMatrix[i][j]);

    }  catch (Exception io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static double[][] transpose(double[][] matrix){
    int m = matrix.length;
    int n = matrix[0].length;

    double[][] transposed = new double[n][m];

    for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < m; y++)
            transposed[x][y] = matrix[y][x];

    return transposed;
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need to transpose the 2D array, you just need to flip `i` and `j` when printing.

Comment: Don't use `sc.close()`, use try-with-resources.